Integrability with respect to Radon measure
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 2$ be a bounded domain. Let $\phi\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ (space of smooth functions with compact support in $\Omega$). Let $f\in L^{\infty}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ and $\mu$ be a nonnegative bounded Radon measure in $\Omega$. Consider the following integral:
$$
I:=\int_{\Omega}f\phi\,d\mu.
$$
My question is does the integral $I$ make sense? If so, is $I<\infty$?
My approach is: if $K=\mathrm{support}\,\phi$, where $\phi\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, then
$$
|I|\leq\|f\|_{L^\infty(K)}\|\phi\|_{L^\infty(K)}\,\mu(K)<\infty.
$$
So $I$ makes sense and $I<\infty$. Please clarify if I am misunderstanding. Thanks.

Yes, it is correct.

Can you please explain? Thanks.

I understand it is finite if $f\in C_c^{1}(\Omega)$ from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure

What do you mean by "bounded"?

My question is if $I$ make sense and if so, is it finite? Thanks.
